# Bitmap decodefile() by filepath displays empty

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development using Kotlin. I'm trying to practice uploading image from a mobile phone to my app using some methods as codes in the code below. everything works just fine with some processes such as I can select on the imageview then screen popup that can let me select image in my phone. unfortunately, after selecting the image, It shows empty/blank, shows nothing in the app. I've tried to search for help but It didn't work out. Hopefully, I can get a hand here. thanks in advance!

**Activity code**

```js
package student

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.example.amazontutoringcenter.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.amazontutoringcenter.databinding.ActivityStudentClassroomBinding
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso



class StudentClassroomActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.imageView.setOnClickListener {
            checkPermission()
        }
    }

    val READ_IMAGE:Int=338
    private fun checkPermission() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(arrayOf( android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),READ_IMAGE)
                return
            }
        }

        loadImage()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

        when(requestCode) {
            READ_IMAGE->{
                if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    loadImage()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Cannot access your images",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
            else-> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        }


    }

    val PICK_IMAGE_CODE=123
    private fun loadImage(){

        var intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_CODE  && data!=null && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            val selectedImage=data.data
            val filePathColum= arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            val cursor= contentResolver.query(selectedImage!!,filePathColum,null,null,null)
            cursor!!.moveToFirst()
            val columnIndex=cursor!!.getColumnIndex(filePathColum[0])
            val picturePath=cursor!!.getString(columnIndex)
            cursor!!.close()
            //.load(picturePath).into(binding.imageStudentProfile)
            //Picasso.get().load(picturePath).fit().into(binding.imageStudentProfile)
            binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath))
        }
    }
}
```

**XML File**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attendant"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the code in `onActivityResult()` that queries the `MediaStore`. Just pass the `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (Glide, Coil, Picasso, etc.).

Comment: Thx man, It's working now

Answer (score 1):

ImageView has a member to load an image from an uri.

And you have an uri `data.data`.

So use it.

Comment: I didn't get it. can you simplify more, please?

Comment: Something like imageView.setImageUri(data.data).

Comment: Thx man, It's working now